# how to solve error :This code is unreachable - in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

```
x = True

def myFunc():
    if x:
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "false"

    print("hello world")
myFunc()
```

This code gave me error as: "This code is unreachable"

Please can you explain why this is ?

Comment: In the `if` statement, you either return from the function, or you return from the function.  How could the `print` ever be executed?  (The assumption is that a programmer would not have wasted time writing code that will never be run - so if that ever appears to be the case, the program clearly does not reflect the programmer's intent.)

Comment: The real problem is code written in an unconscious fashion.

Comment: @DávidHorváth - I think OP was conscious when the code was written. It seems to me that this person is new to programming and isn't used to following code paths. To the author, try following all of the possible code paths - since both the if and the else return to the calling program, nothing else will execute. Code that will never executed is called "unreachable". Its usually a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `return` keywords, the `def` stops when the code runs into a `return` line. It assigns the specified value to the function, and then it will stop. In your case, you have a `bool` type on an `if/else` condition. So `x` must be `True` or `False`, and both cases have a `return` statement. If you want to do anything after that, you should call it outside the original function.

So, with that being said:

```
x = True

def myFunc():
    if x:
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "false"

myFunc()
print("hello world")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like your explanation, except that saying "the `def` stops when the code runs into a `return` line" is misleading.  The function includes ALL of the code down through the `print`.  It's just that the `print` will never be executed because the function will always have returned by then.

Comment: ah, thx for clarifying my answer. I'll be sure to remember it like that next time :)

Answer (score 1):

The code is showing an error because of the presence of the print("hello world") statement after the return statement in the myFunc() function. The return statement is used to exit the function and return a value. Any code after the return statement within the same block of the function will be unreachable and will not be executed.

```
x = True

def myFunc():
    if x:
        print("hello world")
        return "yes"
    else:
        return "false"

result = myFunc()
print(result)
```

Comment: It's not actually an error.  It's just a warning from PyCharm.  There is nothing syntactically wrong with unreachable code.